# R help on aggregation function

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate-functions, aggregate

for my question I created a dummy data frame:

```
    set.seed(007)
 DF <- data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=2), b = sample(40:49), c = sample(1:10))
 DF
   a  b  c
1  A 49  2
2  A 43  3
3  B 40  7
4  B 47  1
5  C 41  9
6  C 48  8
7  D 45  6
8  D 42  5
9  E 46 10
10 E 44  4
```

How can I use the aggregation function on column `a` so that, for instance, for "A" the following value is calculated: 49-43 / 2+3?

I started like:

```
aggregate(DF, by=list(DF$a), FUN=function(x) {

  ...

})
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to access the 4 different cells 49, 43, 2 and 3
I tried `x[[1]][1]` and similar stuff but don't get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `aggregate`, the function `FUN` is applied independently to each column of your data. Here you want to use a function that takes two columns as inputs, so a priori, you can't use `aggregate` for that.

Instead, you can use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(DF, "a", summarize, res = (b[1] - b[2]) / sum(c))
#   a        res
# 1 A  1.2000000
# 2 B -0.8750000
# 3 C -0.4117647
# 4 D  0.2727273
# 5 E  0.1428571
```

Answer (score 2):

When you aggregate the `FUN` argument can be anything you want.  Keep in mind that the value passed will either be a `vector` (if x is one column) or a little `data.frame` or `matrix` (if x is more than one).  However, `aggregate` doesn't let you access the columns of a multi-column argument.  For example.

```
aggregate( . ~ a, data = DF, FUN = function(x) diff(x[,1]) / sum(x[,2]) )
```

That fails with an error even though I used `.` (which takes all of the columns of DF that I'm not using elsewhere).  To see what `aggregate` is trying to do there look at the following.

```
aggregate( . ~ a, data = DF, FUN = sum )
```

The two columns, b, and c, were aggregated but from the first attempt we know that you can't do something that accesses each column separately.  So, strictly sticking with aggregate you need two passes and three lines of code.

```
diffb <- aggregate( b ~ a, data = DF, FUN = diff )
Y <- aggregate( c ~ a, data = DF, FUN = sum )
Y$c <- diffb$b / Y$c
```

Now Y contains the result you want.

The `by` function is simpler than `aggregate` and all it does is split the original `data.frame` using the indices and then apply the `FUN` function.

```
l <- by( data = DF, INDICES = DF$a, FUN = function(x) diff(x$b)/sum(x$c), simplify = FALSE )
unlist(l)
```

You have to do a little to get the result back into a `data.frame` if you really want one.

```
data.frame(a = names(l), x = unlist(l))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` could be faster and easier.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, (-1*diff(b))/sum(c), by=a]
  a         V1
1: A  1.2000000
2: B -0.8750000
3: C -0.4117647
4: D  0.2727273
5: E  0.1428571
```

Using aggregate, not so good. I didn't a better way to do it using `aggregate` :( but here's an attempt.

```
B <- aggregate(DF$b, by=list(DF$a), diff)
C <- aggregate(DF$c, by=list(DF$a), sum)
data.frame(a=B[,1], Result=(-1*B[,2])/C[,2])
  a     Result
1 A  1.2000000
2 B -0.8750000
3 C -0.4117647
4 D  0.2727273
5 E  0.1428571
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution - for efficiency of time and memory.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)

DT[, list(calc = diff(b) / sum(c)), by = a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base [`by()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/by.html) function:

```
listOfRows <- 
by(data=DF,
   INDICES=DF$a,
   FUN=function(x){data.frame(a=x$a[1],res=(x$b[1] - x$b[2])/(x$c[1] + x$c[2]))})

newDF <- do.call(rbind,listOfRows)
```